# CallBack seems to exit with no reason on stream reading

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcpclient

```
    Private Sub Receiving(ByVal iAr As IAsyncResult)
    Console.WriteLine("Receiving callback started" + vbNewLine)
    Try
        SyncLock client.GetStream
            Try
                client.GetStream.EndRead(iAr)
            Catch
                Console.WriteLine("exciting")
                Exit Sub
            End Try
        End SyncLock
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("exciting")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim sReader As StreamReader
    Dim nChar As Integer
    Dim StrBuffer(4096) As Char

    SyncLock client.GetStream
        sReader = New StreamReader(client.GetStream)

        Try
            nChar = sReader.Read(StrBuffer, 0, bByte.Length)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
        End Try


        Console.WriteLine(client.GetStream.CanRead)
        newStr = New String(StrBuffer, 0, nChar)

        Console.WriteLine(newStr)

        Console.WriteLine("Receiving callback callbacked" + vbNewLine)

        client.GetStream.BeginRead(bByte, 0, 4096, AddressOf Receiving, Nothing)
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

This is the code I have, I've been debugging for maybe an hour and I can't find the problem, therefore I can't find a solution

What should happen is the receiving method get an array of byte, in debugging the array is not empty I,ve checked, but where it seems to be a problem is on the line where it read

```
nChar = sReader.Read(StrBuffer, 0, bByte.Length)
```

at this line the debugging just stop nothing to do, if I remove the line the function continue but the problem is on this line and I really don't know what could cause this.

if you need more information ask me, i'm very confused with this thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When EndRead() is executed the data received is **already** inside your byte array "bByte".  The returned value from EndRead() will be the number of bytes read.  You're attempting to read again down below with the StreamReader, but you've already got the data in your buffer before that point.

I'm not sure how you encoded the data, but typically you'd do something more like this on the receiving side:

```
Private Sub Receiving(ByVal iAr As IAsyncResult)
    Console.WriteLine("Receiving callback started" + vbNewLine)
    Dim nChar As Integer = client.GetStream.EndRead(iAr)
    Dim newStr As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bByte, 0, nChar)
    Console.WriteLine(newStr)
    Console.WriteLine("Receiving callback callbacked" + vbNewLine)
    client.GetStream.BeginRead(bByte, 0, bByte.Length, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Receiving), Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: I added the EndRead since MSDN was saying ti was requested ... but thank you it effectivly make alot of sense now